# jQuery UI dialog box using .load, how to close dialog box upon selection from a drop down list

Tags: jquery-ui

I have a webpage that has some textboxes on it. When a user clicks on one of the text boxes a jQuery UI dialog box opens using the `.load` to load a HTML page containing the following:

```
<select name="resp" id="input" onclick="parent.mfac_value(this.form.resp.value);">
    <option value="Choice">
    <option value="APC">APC</OPTION>
    <option value="APPLE">APPLE</OPTION>
    <option value="XEROX">XEROX</OPTION>
</select>
```

I am succesfully returning the value to the parent textbox via `parent.mfac_falue` function but the modal window does not autoclose upon the selection of the item, which is what I want to happen.

How can I get the modal window to autoclose immediately after someone selects an item from the dropdown box?  Let me know if you need more info, thank you.

**Update:**

Actually, where would I put the `.closest` code.  Would it be in the HTML file that is called or the parent file. I am having trouble getting the solution to work.

Answer (score 0):

You can attach an event handler to it, I would use `.change()` here, like this:

```
$("#input").change(function() {
  $(this).closest(".ui-dialog-content").dialog("close");
});
```

This goes up to the dialog container, finding it via [`.closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) and the `.ui-dialog-content` selector (the class the dialog widget gave it) then calls the [`close` method on dialog](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#method-close).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
onchange="parent.mfac_value(this.form.resp.value);$('#ID_OF_DIALOG').dialog('close');"
```